# Як правильно називається 10^45 за короткою шкалою (10^84 за довгою), англ. quattuordecillion?

Tags: переклад, правопис, числівники

Для чого: роблю переклад Rust-крейта num2words українською.

[Стаття на Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D1%96) каже "кваттуордецильйон", і це виглядає трохи не узгоджено з іншими назвами там же, на кшталт квадрильйона, кваттортрігінтильйона чи квадрагінтильйона.

Пошук "кваттордецильйон" дає лише два посилання, обидва не дуже серйозні.

"Кватродецильйон" - теж не густо, але згадується на тій же [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_10).

[Словники](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=quattuordecillion&dicts=all) кажуть "кватордецильйон", але Гугл такого слова не знає.

Узагалі жодного прикладу "живого" використання цього числа не гуглиться, лише в табличках, переважно скопійованих з Вікі.

Яке слово правильно використовувати?

Додатково: може, варто виправити Вікі з посиланням на Мейнаровича?

Ще додатково: разом пишемо складні порядкові числівники, останнім компонентом яких є -сотий, -тисячний, -мільйонний, -мільярдний (Правопис, параграф 38). А -трильйонний і вищі?